# Adding slider under the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I have the following slider that uses flexslider:

```
    <div class="wrapper bgded overlay" id="home-page">
    <div id="pageintro" class="hoc clear">
        <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
        <div class="flexslider basicslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                {% for news in latest_news %}
                <li>
                    <article>
                        <p>Новости и мероприятия:</p>
                        <h3 class="heading"><a href="{% url 'paparazzi:news_specific' news.id %}">{{ news.title }}</a></h3>

                    </article>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the jquery code for the another slider that changes background image of the flexslider( layer behind the flexslider). But for some unknown reasons the background image isn't changing after the given time.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var header = $('#home-page').get(0).id;

        var backgrounds = new Array(
            'http://placekitten.com/100',
            'http://placekitten.com/300',
            'http://placekitten.com/200',
        )

        var current = 0;

        function nextBackground() {
            current++;
            current = current % backgrounds.length;
            header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
        }

        setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

        header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're storing the header's id in the variable `header`, and not the actual header DOM node, so you're trying to change the background image of a string variable.

I think this:

```
var header = $('#home-page').get(0).id;
```

Should be:

```
var header = $('#home-page');
```

Also, if you want to change the background-image css you need to set the complete string with the "url" part, like you do in css:

```
header.css('background-image', 'url(' + backgrounds[current] + ')');
```

Wrapping up, here's the full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        var header = $('#home-page');

        var backgrounds = new Array(
            'http://placekitten.com/100',
            'http://placekitten.com/300',
            'http://placekitten.com/200',
        )

        var current = 0;

        function nextBackground() {
            current++;
            current = current % backgrounds.length;
            header.css('background-image', "url(" + backgrounds[current] + ")");
        }

        setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

        header.css('background-image',"url(" +  backgrounds[0] + ")");

    });
```

```css
#home-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-page">

</div>
```

One last small note, when I work with jQuery I usually begin variable names with "$" so I know immediately what they are, so your `header` variable would be called `$header`, this is not required, of course, but it helps keeping things readable.